# How to pass value on tailwind dropdown that uses a tag for livewire

Tags: list, tailwind-css, laravel-livewire

I am working on a project with Tailwind. I want to use the tailwind class for the table list with livewire.

The project has list of tasks that has search box and I want to add more filter options. So for example:
List by ID or Title...

So I can use the traditional `select` and `option` with livewire. But tailwind provides code with `div`, `ul` and `a` tags.

How to pass the value if I use `a` tag. For example:

```
<select wire:model.live="sortBy">
            <option value="title">Sort by title</option>
            <option value="id">Sort by id</option>
        </select>
```

How to use the above livewire directive in the below code and pass the value to livewire component?

See the tailwind for dropdown:

```
<div>
            <button id="dropdownActionButton" data-dropdown-toggle="dropdownAction" class="inline-flex items-center text-gray-500 bg-white border border-gray-300 focus:outline-none hover:bg-gray-100 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-200 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-3 py-1.5 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-gray-400 dark:border-gray-600 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:border-gray-600 dark:focus:ring-gray-700" type="button">
                <span class="sr-only">Action button</span>
                Action
                <svg class="w-2.5 h-2.5 ms-2.5" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 10 6">
                    <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="m1 1 4 4 4-4"/>
                </svg>
            </button>
            <!-- Dropdown menu -->
            <div id="dropdownAction" class="z-10 hidden bg-white divide-y divide-gray-100 rounded-lg shadow w-44 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:divide-gray-600">
                <ul class="py-1 text-sm text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200" aria-labelledby="dropdownActionButton">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">Reward</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">Promote</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">Activate account</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="py-1">
                    <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:text-gray-200 dark:hover:text-white">Delete User</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking

Comment: How to use livewire directive with tailwind dropdown style that uses div, a, ul, li tags for dropdown if I skip traditional select tag..Main part is to pass the value...

Answer (score 0):

This dropdown menu comes from Flowbite and uses custom JavaScript code to work, visit [this page](https://flowbite.com/docs/getting-started/laravel/) for details.
The purpose of this component is to redirect somewhere using the <a> tag, like a submenu, not to hold a value like a <select>. However we can adapt it to make it select a value.

The *Livewire class*:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class Dropd extends Component
{
    public $theValue;


    public function setTheValue($newValue)
    {
        $this->theValue = $newValue;
    }
}
```

The view:

```html
<div>

    <button type="button"
            id="dropdownActionButton"
            x-ref="dropdownActionButton"
            data-dropdown-toggle="dropdownAction"
            class="inline-flex items-center text-gray-500 bg-white border border-gray-300 focus:outline-none
                   hover:bg-gray-100 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-200 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-3 py-1.5
                   dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-gray-400 dark:border-gray-600 dark:hover:bg-gray-700
                   dark:hover:border-gray-600 dark:focus:ring-gray-700"
    >
        <span class="sr-only">Action button</span>
        Action
        <svg class="w-2.5 h-2.5 ms-2.5" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 10 6">
            <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="m1 1 4 4 4-4"/>
        </svg>

    </button>

    <!-- Dropdown menu -->
    <div id="dropdownAction" class="z-10 hidden bg-white divide-y divide-gray-100 rounded-lg shadow w-44 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:divide-gray-600">

        <ul class="py-1 text-sm text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200" aria-labelledby="dropdownActionButton">

            <li>
                <a href="http://www.google.com"
                   class="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white"
                >
                    Reward
                </a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#"
                   class="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white"
                   wire:click.prevent="setTheValue('Promote')"
                >
                    Promote
                </a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#"
                   class="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white"
                   @click="$wire.theValue = 'Activate account';$refs.dropdownActionButton.click()"
                >
                    Activate account
                </a>
            </li>

        </ul>

        <div class="py-1">

            <a href="#"
               class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:text-gray-200 dark:hover:text-white"
            >
                Delete User
            </a>

        </div>

    </div>

    <button class="flex mt-6 ml-4 px-1 text-gray-500 bg-white border border-gray-300"
            wire:click="$refresh"
    >
        Send
    </button>

    <div class="flex mt-3 ml-4">
        Value: {{ $theValue }}
    </div>

</div>
```

In this example:

- the first menu item redirects to an URL as described above
- the second item calls the *setTheValue()* function via *Livewire* to change the *$theValue* property and the view is automatically updated
- the third item uses *AlpineJs* to change locally the *$theValue* property (this mode requires a forced *click()* to close the list) but you must use the *button Send* to refresh the view